# How to convert GoogleDriveFile to PIL Image or ndarray?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to process some images in google colab. These images are fetched using drive.CreateFile.

```
 im = drive.CreateFile({'id':'<fileid>'})

 new_dim = [toTensor(im).shape[1:][0] / scale_factor, toTensor(im).shape[1:][1] / scale_factor]
    """
   if not(_is_pil_image(pic) or _is_numpy_image(pic)):
        raise TypeError('pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got {}'.format(type(pic)))
   if isinstance(pic, np.ndarray):

TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class 'pydrive.files.GoogleDriveFile'>
```

I can't find any method to change the format of the file.